# behavior of frameset with external link

Tags: asp-classic, external, frameset, sap-ariba

Hope you will be able to help.

We are currently trying to developp a connection between our ASP-classic web site and the Ariba plateform for a punch-out catalogue. The problem we encounter now is that, once the connection is made, our web site appears inside an old-fashion FRAMESET. And surprisingly, in this case, no item can be loaded in the basket. No error, just not filling the basket.

When I simulate locally a similar FRAMESET, I reproduce the phenomenon. But if, instead of https://www.my_site.com/my_page.asp (or http://www.my_site.com/my_page.asp), I put /my page.asp, I can put into the basket.

Knowing that to put into the basket it goes through 2 intermediate ASP pages (calling stored procedures, virtual includes, include file, a POST form) before going to the basket page.

Any clues  or ideas where I loose it?

Edit : actually I just noticed that it's only with Firefox. That works fine with Chrome or IE. Independently I already notice that Firefox is the only one to record in its history one of the 2 intermediate pages while Chrome and IE record no intermediate pages.

Here is the first of the 2 intermediate pages :

```
<%response.Charset="ISO-8859-1"%>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript RUNAT=Server>
function CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2(CT_Num, AR_Ref, CT_Num_B, LI_No) {
    var _CT_Num = CT_Num;
    var _AR_Ref = AR_Ref;
    var _CT_Num_B = CT_Num_B;
    var _LI_No = LI_No;
    var CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2.ActiveConnection = MM_siteSQL_STRING;
    CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2.source = "CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2('" + _CT_Num + "', '" + _AR_Ref + "', '" + _CT_Num_B + "','"  + _LI_No + "')";
    CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2.CursorType = 0
    CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2.CursorLocation = 2;
    CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2.LockType = 1;
    CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2.Open();

return CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2;
}

function escapeChar(maChaine) {
    return escape(maChaine);
}
</SCRIPT>
<%
Dim chnSQL
Dim chnChapitre
chnChapitre = "prod"

Dim chnDecorTbl
Dim entNum
EntNum = 1


Dim chnType, chnInfoProd, entNumPage

chnInfoProd = Trim(Request.Form("InfoProd"))


Dim objJEprod
Dim chnLien, chnPromo, chnBreve, chnRecomb  
Dim Adresse     

If ("undefined" = CStr(Session("monNumero")) or "" = CStr(Session("monNumero"))) Then
    Adresse = -1
Else
    Adresse = Session("monNumero")
End if


Set objJEprod = CalculEtObtentionDuMeilleurPrixEtDesInfosAssociees_v2(Session("MM_UserID"), UCase(Trim(Request.Form("Infoprod"))), Session("CT_Num_B"), Adresse)

IF objJEprod("Reference") = -1 THEN

    Response.Redirect("/recherche-produits.asp?Type=recherche&Statut=vide&InfoProd=" & chnInfoProd )

ELSE

    IF CDbl(objJEprod.Fields.Item("Remise").Value) > 0 THEN
        Session("affichage_remise_promo") = "O"
    END IF

Dim entNumprod, chnDesign
entNumProd = 0

Session("monLien") = ""
Session("EPST") = ""
Session("image") = ""

Session("monLien") = fctUniCode(objJEprod.Fields.Item("Designation").Value)
%>


<!--#include virtual="/inclusion.asp" -->
<% Dim entProdCmd
Dim tblProd
Dim chnSQLprodCmd
Dim entDispoProd
Dim chnMsgDispo
Dim chnImgDispo
Dim chnSQLfamDispo
%>
<!--#include virtual="/inclusion_dispo.asp" -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />


        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" /> 
<link href="/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/google_analytics.js"></script>           


    </head>
<BODY topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" onLoad="document.form_panier1.submit()">
<FORM action="/ajout.asp?PagePrec=<% if Replace(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"), "recherche-produits.asp", "") <> Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") then %>ListeRecherche<% end if %>" method="POST" name="form_panier1" id="form_panier1">

<%

Dim chnPrix
Dim prixPanier      

        chnPrix = objJEprod.Fields.Item("Prix").Value & "&nbsp;&euro;&nbsp;HT"
        prixPanier = objJEprod.Fields.Item("Prix").Value                


if Request.Form("Dispo") <> "" then 
    chnDispo = Request.Form("Dispo")
end if
%>

  <INPUT name="Qte" type="hidden" id="Qte" value="<% If (True = objJEprod.Fields.Item("promotion_offre_liee").Value) Then Response.Write("1") Else Response.Write("1") End if %>">
  <INPUT name="CachProductID" type="hidden" id="CachProductID" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Reference").Value%>">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="UC_recordId" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Reference").Value%>">
  <INPUT name="CachPrice" type="hidden" id="CachPrice" value="<%=prixPanier%>">
  <INPUT name="hiddenRef" type="hidden" id="hiddenRef" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Reference").Value%>">
  <INPUT name="hiddenConditionnement" type="hidden" id="hiddenConditionnement" value="<%=escapeChar(objJEprod.Fields.Item("Conditionnement").Value)%>">
  <INPUT name="hiddenName" type="hidden" id="hiddenName" value="<%=Session("EPST") & Session("image") & fctUniCode(chnDispo) %>">  
  <INPUT name="hiddenNameEnr" type="hidden" id="hiddenNameEnr" value="<%=Session("monLien")%>">

  <INPUT name="hiddenchnPromo" type="hidden" id="hiddenchnPromo" value="<%=Session("chnPromo")%>">
  <INPUT name="CachdenRemise" type="hidden" id="CachdenRemise" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Remise").Value%>">
  <INPUT name="CachdenPrix_Remise" type="hidden" id="CachdenPrix_Remise" value="<%=replace(objJEprod.Fields.Item("Prix_remise").Value,",",".") %>">
  <INPUT name="CachCode_promo_et_date" type="hidden" id="CachCode_promo_et_date" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Code_promo_plus_date_de_fin_de_validite").Value%>">
  <INPUT name="CachCode_promo" type="hidden" id="CachCode_promo" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Code_promo").Value%>">

  <INPUT name="Cachtype" type="hidden" id="Cachtype" value="ecom">
  <INPUT name="Cachpromotion_offre_liee" type="hidden" id="Cachpromotion_offre_liee" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("promotion_offre_liee").Value%>">
  <INPUT name="Cachpromotion_par_quantite_bit" type="hidden" id="Cachpromotion_par_quantite_bit" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("promotion_par_quantite_bit").Value%>">
  <INPUT name="CachExisteStock" type="hidden" id="CachExisteStock" value="<%=objJEprod.Fields.Item("Stock").Value%>">

  <input type="hidden" name="PagePrec" value="<%=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")%>" />
</FORM>         

<%

END IF

'Élimination des objets ADO
'**************************
objJEprod.Close
Set objJEprod = Nothing

'Fermeture de la connexion
'*************************
objConxn.Close
Set objConxn = Nothing

%>


</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: I don't see how we have any hope of helping you unless you post some code. What's the code of the page that works in Chrome/IE but not in Firefox?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I was hoping that somebody encouter a similar problem whitout having to insert so many lines of code. Suddenly I am wondering: could it be due to the onLoad of the form ?

Comment: After futher testing it seems IE encounters the same problem as Firefox.It's possible to put into the basket only with Chrome.